# NBitcoin -- How do I just check the balance of my wallet from my seed phrase?

Tags: c#, nbitcoin

I've looked through [the docs](https://github.com/NicolasDorier/NBitcoin.Docs), I've Googled, I've searched here, and it all just seems like Greek to me... I must not be using the right keywords, because I just can't figure out what I think should be the most dead-simple thing...

How can I use NBitcoin to open my wallet from my 12 word seed phrase and look at the balance? I feel like if I can just get some help getting that far, I can probably go from there to do more...

Also, does NBitcoin have an API reference guide?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `var key = mnemoObj.DeriveExtKey();` then you can derive addresses as explained in this chapter (https://programmingblockchain.gitbook.io/programmingblockchain/key_generation).

```
mnemo = new Mnemonic("minute put grant neglect anxiety case globe win famous correct turn link",
                Wordlist.English);
hdRoot = mnemo.DeriveExtKey("my password");
```

Comment: thanks, this finally got me started 